# How does the URL redirection work for Meteor and Godaddy

Tags: web, meteor, dns

I have deployed my meteor app to some random name/url.  I own the actual URL I want , myapp.com, at Godaddy.  I did not deploy to that URL literally because I did not understand how the URL at Godaddy was going to be used at meteor.  I believed I would have to do something over at Godaddy after I deployed.  Now, I am ready to deploy with myapp.com on the meteor command line.  What is going to happen?  What steps will I have to take to make sure the url is properly directed over to the galaxy servers?  I have read [this article](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-galaxy-dns-settings-not-working-with-godaddy-domain/37876) and the CNAME for my URL at Godaddy is already set to Eastern Us galaxy server.  How does all this work?

Edit:
So, I was able to deploy to [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) and this all worked.  But then, when I wanted to type maypp.com into the browser, it failed.  I was able to get to my site by typing [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) into the browser, but this is not what I want.  When I deleted this app and redeployed to myapp.com, I could not connect no matter what and I was refused when generating the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If your CNAME DNS record for myapp.com is set to point at the galaxy servers, then it should work once you run `meteor deploy myapp.com`. The mechanism behind this is a type of [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy): The server that responds to the incoming HTTP(s) request will inspect the request and see under what name it was reached, in your case `myapp.com`. Based on that information, the reverse proxy redirects the request to the internal resource that runs your app.

Comment: I made some updates to this question.  Can you have a look?